# Running a locally-defined function remotely

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I have a Powershell script with some functions, and one of these functions I want to run remotely (it takes parameters and returns void) from within an Invoke-Command block.

I am using Powershell 5. How can I best achieve this?

Many Thanks!

Comment: Code sign the function as a module then on the remote client just import that module from a network location.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an object of type `FunctionInfo` to the remote command and then recreate the function on the other side. Lets say you have a function:

```
function foo($a) { write-host "foo says: $a" }
```

Then you can obtain a FunctionInfo:

```
$f = get-item function:\foo
```

Now pass it as an argument to remote command:

```
Invoke-Command "computer1" { 
    param($fobj) 
    invoke-expression "function $($fobj.name) { $($fobj.ScriptBlock) }"
    foo "hello!"
} -ArgumentList $f
```

(Note that you cannot just do `set-item function:\foo $fobj`, because on the other side `$fobj` is of type `PSObject`, not `FunctionInfo`).

If `foo` calls some other functions that are defined on the local machine, you would have to pass them over too. Therefore, this technique is useful only for really simple functions. For more complicated ones, consider encapsulating them in a module and installing that module on remote machine.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can pass function as an argument as mentioned, But instead of using `Get-Item` it is better to use `$Variable = Get-Content Function:\Foo` and pass it into `invoke-Command` as using `Invoke-Expression` is not a Best Practice.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName -$Server -ScriptBlock {Param($Var1)
$Var1 #This will execute your function as usual.
} -ArgumentList $Variable
```

$Var1 will be of type `System.Management.Automation.FunctionInfo`

If you have parameters to your function, You have to pass then as well with

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName -$Server -ScriptBlock {Param($Var1,$Par1,$Par2)
$Var1 $Par1 $Par2 #This will execute your function as usual.
} -ArgumentList $Variable,$Param1,$Param2
```

It would be nice if you read `Get-Help Invoke-Command -Parameter Argumentlist`

and

https://powershell.org/2012/08/06/ebook-secrets-of-powershell-remoting/

regards,

kvprasoon